# How to show menu item in action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I want the menu items to show on action bar. There is a lot of space on the ActionBar, but still they don't show up. Every item shown as three dots, why?

.java file

```
public class GalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gallery_layout);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:MissionAndroid="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/facebookId"
            android:title="facebook"
            android:icon="@drawable/facebook"
            MissionAndroid:showAsAction="always"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/shareId"
            android:title="share"
            android:icon="@drawable/share"
            MissionAndroid:showAsAction="always"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:title="delete"
            android:icon="@drawable/delete"
            MissionAndroid:showAsAction="always"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/searchId"
            android:title="search"
            android:icon="@drawable/search"
            MissionAndroid:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    </menu>
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you're using `"http://schemas.android.com/tools"` which does not offer the functionality you're looking for and your `showAsAction` modifiers are being ignored.

Try updating your main_menu.xml with the following:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:MissionAndroid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    ...

</menu>
```

Better yet, to follow convention, replace `MissionAndroid` in this file with `app`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/facebookId"
        android:title="facebook"
        android:icon="@drawable/facebook"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    ...

</menu>
```